# How can I configure the live dashboard and a JSON API under the same scope?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm setting up an API server, and I'd like to include a live dashboard. I don't want to scope the routes under `/api` and I'd like to be able to host the dashboard at `/dashboard`, but I'd settle for being able to run it at `/admin/dashboard`.

Here's my attempt at setting up the router:

```
defmodule ExampleApiWeb.Router do
  use ExampleApiWeb, :router
  import Phoenix.LiveDashboard.Router

  pipeline :admin do
    plug :fetch_session
    plug :protect_from_forgery
  end

  pipeline :api do
    plug :accepts, ["json"]
  end

  scope "/", ExampleApiWeb do
    pipe_through :api
  end

  scope "/admin" do
    pipe_through :admin
    live_dashboard "/dashboard", metrics: ExampleApiWeb.Telemetry
  end
end
```

When I try to run the server, I get this error:

```
[debug] ** (Phoenix.Router.NoRouteError) no route found for GET /dashboard/home (ExampleApiWeb.Router)
```

How can I host the dashboard under a different scope? And is it possible to host the regular API and the dashboard both under the same root scope?

Comment: You have put in scope admin. The url should be prefixed by admin. Something like: `localhost:4000/admin/dashboard`

Comment: @franckstifler Thanks for the reply! I'm not sure how I missed that. Do you know if there's any way to leave the dashboard at the root and redirect the other root traffic through a different pipe?

Comment: You can use `mix phx.routes` to see all the available routes in your Phoenix application. Perhaps that helps in the future. https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Mix.Tasks.Phx.Routes.html